# Compiler wont rebuild files smaller than 4kB

Tags: reactjs, npm, vite

My images work completely find in my local device but I couldn't load them in my staging site, then I found out it wasn't being rebuilt into the dist>asset folder. I am not sure if this is a legitimate thing but I edited the image file and tweaked the file size and I found out that as long as the image file is smaller than 4kB, it will not get rebuilt into my dist>asset folder.

I couldn't find any answers online as to why this is a thing, but if this is fix-able how can I remove this limitation?

Comment: I think its because vite inlined asset below 4kB https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options.html#build-assetsinlinelimit,